# android onclick for swipe layout in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-canvas, onclicklistener

I attached `simpleItemTouchCallback` to `recyclerView` for  swiping items in the list.

```
              @Override
              public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
                        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                        float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                        float width = height / 3;
                        if (dX / 3 > 0) {
                            RectF rect = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft(), (float) itemView.getTop(), dX / 3, (float) itemView.getBottom());
                            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            View v = li.inflate(R.layout.complete_layout, null);
                            v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredWidth()), View.MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
                            v.layout(0, 0, Math.round(rect.width()), Math.round(rect.height()));
                            c.save();
                            c.translate(rect.left, rect.top);
                            v.draw(c);
                        } else {
                            RectF rect1 = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX / 3, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                            LayoutInflater li1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            View v = li1.inflate(R.layout.delete_layout, null);
                            v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredWidth()), View.MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
                            v.layout(0, 0, Math.round(rect1.width()), Math.round(rect1.height()));
                            c.save();
                            c.translate(rect1.left, rect1.top);
                            v.draw(c);
                        }
                        c.restore();
                    }
 super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX / 3, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
```

Swiping and drawing new layout is working properly. Now want add an `OnClickListener` to the new layout. I couldn't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work. But in my code the views are not clickable at all. Maybe it is working for you.

```
RectF rect1 = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX / 3, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
LayoutInflater li1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = li1.inflate(R.layout.delete_layout, null);
v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredWidth()), View.MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
v.layout(0, 0, Math.round(rect1.width()), Math.round(rect1.height()));
c.save();
c.translate(rect1.left, rect1.top); 

v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // implement here your code for the click
                }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
       //Magic happens here
    }
}
```

Btw: I have no idea what you are doing inside the method you posted up^^